# Why won't rails recognize my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, rails-activerecord

Would love to hear someone's take on this. My rails app is connected to the development database and all my models work fine except for one. As far as the app is concerned, the "Message" model does not exist, even though the table was created and can be seen in the schema.rb file. Has anyone run into this before? I've checked the spelling on all my model filenames, so unless I'm completely oblivious, I don't think that's it. The model looks like so:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  attr_accessible :content, :prescription, :type, :to, :sent_at, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_many :adherences
  has_many :patients, :through => :adherences
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 160 }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patients
end
```

Rails console output shows nothing:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > Message.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for Message:Class
    from (irb):1
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

1.9.3-p194 :004 > Message.inspect
"Message"
```

the db created the Messages table though. the schema.rb (abbreviated):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130613020005) do

  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.string   "type"
    t.string   "prescription"
    t.string   "to"
    t.datetime "sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

The only thing I can think of is that a "Message" model exists somewhere in one of the gems I'm using or a dependency thereof. But it was working fine earlier then all of a sudden, wasn't.

Here are the more recently installed gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sms-spec'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

If anyone has come across this or something similar I'd be interested to hear what your situation was. There may be other problems with the associations and whatnot, but that doesn't seem to be the problem from what I can tell.

Comment: `Message.class` and `Message.superclass` might help you find out if it's being defined by another part of Rails

Comment: `Message.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base)` and `Message.class.methods.sort` might help too

Comment: Did you run rake task `migrate` after creating migration? (I know is unlikely, but what if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is a conflicting "message" method in the `growl` gem. I will need to find a workaround or remove that gem.